# How to float divs with different heights?

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve:

[image]

What I currently get: (the second box has an extra list item that messes up the whole layout)
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="categories">
    <div class="cat">   cat1    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat2    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat3    </div>
    <div class="cat"> cat4 </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat5    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat6    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat7    </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat8    </div>
    <div class="cat"> cat9 </div>
    <div class="cat">   cat10   </div>
</div>
```

One solution would be to group five items in a new div and apply `clear:left` but I can't do that due to how the php code works.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do this a lot, and constantly come back to this reference:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/

I think this will help you achieve what you're after.

Comment: Beautiful, Jon! Works great, will definitely use this in the future too!

Answer (score 3):

Would you not just display all the div's inline-block?

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure why you can't do the clear left due to how php code works.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) { 
  echo '<div class="cat"> cat '. $i .' </div>';
  if ( $i%5 == 0 ) {
    echo '<div style="clear: left;"></div>';
  }
  $i++
}
?>
```

Otherwise a non-php solution would be [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/gCEDV/

**html**

```
<div id="categories">
    <div class="cat cat1 square">   cat1    </div>
    <div class="cat cat2 square">   cat2    </div>
    <div class="cat cat3 tall">   cat3    </div>
    <div class="cat cat4 square"> cat4 </div>
    <div class="cat cat5 long">   cat5    </div>
    <div class="cat cat6 tall">   cat6    </div>
    <div class="cat cat7 square">   cat7    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
div.cat {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#categories {
    width: 230px;
}
.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.long {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.tall {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: i think (i could be wrong) that the question is regarding dynamic content where the height of elements cannot be set explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You may struggle with the height of each container, as it will be set to whatever is inside it. You could grab the elements with something like jQuery to manipulate the DOM for each div container afterwards if height is important and there isn't enough content inside the boxes to stretch them.

As far as horizontal spacing goes, each of these elements could share a CSS class with the same padding?

Block 5 is achievable if each of your containers have explicit widths and the parent container has an explicit width.